# When spring-boot app multi-node deploy， how to handle cron job?

Tags: spring-boot, schedule

When I use spring task handle a simple sync job! But when I deploy multi-node, how I make sure the cron job just run one time.
Maybe you say that:
1. Use distributed-lock control a flag before the crob job run.
2. Integrated quartz cluster function.
But I hope spring task @EnableScheduling can add a flag argument, so as we can set a flag when launch app.

Answer (score 1):

We are using https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock with success, zookeeper provider in particular.

Comment: It's good for work. I think if the project provide a global lock for spring-boot application is better. For example, if I annotation a `@SingleUse` and give a check health in some time will be last solution.   `@SpringBootApplication @EnableScheduling @SingleUse(checkTime=10000)`

Comment: @clandestino_bgd, can you provide please  a link to an example with zookeeper provider. There's no much information in the documentation and we face many issues. I.e zookeeper 3.4.10 net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-provider-zookeeper-curator:3.0.0, curator-x-async:4.2.10 leads to errors like "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.curator.framework.api.CreateBuilder.creatingParentsIfNeeded()Lorg/apache/curator/framework/api/ProtectACLCreateModeStatPathAndBytesable;"

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot, in a nutshell, doesn't allow any type of coordination between multiple instances 
of the same microservice.

All the work of such a coordination is done by the third parties that spring boot gets integrated with.

One example of this is indeed a `@Scheduled` annotation.

Another is DB migration support via *flyway*.

When many nodes start and the migration has to be done, flyway is responsible to lock the migration table by itself, spring boot has nothing to do with it.

So, bottom line, there is no such support and all options that you've raised can work.